I am getting this error Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
I cat some logfiles into a python script which I then pipe into head as follows:
cat *mongodb.log.* | python jsonFetcher.py -b 20240101000000 -e 20250101000000 | head

the output is as follows, I am getting the error at the end. I don't get the error when piping to another python script:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-09T02:47:32.053+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.240.198:57790","uuid":"8e485191-5c63-457e-b341-14515b593ef1","connectionId":207933,"connectionCount":773}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-09T02:47:32.084+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn207932","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.240.198:57776","client":"conn207932","negotiatedCompressors":[],"doc":{"application":{"name":"MongoDB Automation Agent v13.16.2.8826 (git: 36d72fa13b663f402e1285ab8458536766897530)"},"driver":{"name":"mongo-go-driver","version":"v1.12.0-cloud"},"os":{"type":"linux","architecture":"arm64"},"platform":"go1.21.10"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-06-09T02:47:32.085+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.240.198:57794","uuid":"3d76d2c2-2298-4fc8-80b6-e029d0d1f933","connectionId":207934,"connectionCount":774}}
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Here is the script sending head its input:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""

 File: jsonFetcher.py
 Author: Dennis Spera
 Date: 2024-06-24
 Description: Extract json from mongod.log on stdin based on date ranges.

"""

import sys
import json as j
from datetime import datetime
import re as regex
from commandlines import Command as cmd

b = str()
e = str()
start_d_t_fmt = None
end_d_t_fmt = None
max_input_length = 14
min_input_length = 8

def is_json(json):
    try:
        j.loads(json)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

try:
  c = cmd()
  
  try:  
       b = c.get_definition('b') 
       if len(b) > max_input_length:
           sys.stderr.write('beginning timestamp exceeds beginning timesamp length of ' + str(max_input_length))
           sys.exit(0)
       if len(b) < min_input_length:
           sys.stderr.write('beginning timestamp less than beginning timesamp length of ' + str(min_input_length))
           sys.exit(0)           

       try:
          test = int(b) 
       except:
           sys.stderr.write('beginning timestamp is an invalid data format')
           sys.exit(0)      

       padding = max_input_length - len(b)             

       if padding > 0: 
          for i in range(1, padding+1, 1):
              b=b+'0'
  
       e = c.get_definition('e') 
       if len(e) > max_input_length:
           sys.stderr.write('ending timestamp exceeds ending timesamp length of ' + str(max_input_length))
           sys.exit(0)
       if len(b) < min_input_length:
           sys.stderr.write('ending timestamp less than ending timesamp length of ' + str(min_input_length))
           sys.exit(0)           

       try:
          test = int(e) 
       except:
           sys.stderr.write('end timestamp is an invalid data format')
           sys.exit(0)      

       padding = max_input_length - len(e)             

       if padding > 0: 
          for i in range(1, padding+1, 1):
              e=e+'0'
                
  except:
        sys.stderr.write('error parsing input parameters')
        sys.exit(0) 

  for line in sys.stdin:
     if is_json(line):

        d = j.loads(line)
        dateT = d["t"]["$date"]

        match_object = regex.match( r'(\d{4})([-])(\d{2})([-])(\d{2})([T])(\d{2})([:])(\d{2})([:])(\d{2})(.*)', dateT)
        d_t_fmt = datetime.strptime(match_object.group(1)+match_object.group(3)\
                                   +match_object.group(5)\
                                   +match_object.group(7)+match_object.group(9)
                                   +match_object.group(11), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')  
        
        match_object = regex.match( r'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})',  b) 

        try:
          start_d_t_fmt = datetime.strptime(match_object.group(1)+match_object.group(2)\
                                                       +match_object.group(3)\
                                                       +match_object.group(4)+match_object.group(5)
                                                       +match_object.group(6), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        except:
                 sys.stderr.write('error converting start date-time to a datatime format')  

        match_object = regex.match( r'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})',  e) 

        try:
          end_d_t_fmt = datetime.strptime(match_object.group(1)+match_object.group(2)\
                                                       +match_object.group(3)\
                                                       +match_object.group(4)+match_object.group(5)
                                                       +match_object.group(6), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        except:
                 sys.stderr.write('error converting end date-time to a datatime format')  

        if (start_d_t_fmt <= d_t_fmt) and (end_d_t_fmt >= d_t_fmt) and not regex.match(r'^$', line):
            print(line,end="")


  sys.stdin.close()

except OSError as err:
  print('!!! ',err)

All my reseach seems to point at directory naming on windows, all though I am not writing to any files

After head has read 10 lines it exits, which closes the read end of the stdout pipe. This causes print(line, end="") to get an error when it tries to write lines past 10 (actually somewhat later, because output is buffered -- the error happens when the buffer is flushed).
If you pipe to another script, it's probably not exiting until it has read all of its input, so you don't get an error writing to the pipe.

thank you, that makes sense. What is the difference  if I do this
% cat some_large_text_file | head, that doesn't give an error.

cat ignores the error silently.

What actually happens is it gets a SIGPIPE signal, which causes it to exit immediately. The shell doesn't report when programs that are in a pipeline are killed by this signal.

Thank you @Barmar, I wrote the head as a Python script to navigate this issue.  Your assistance is appreciated.
